# Paypal button won't appear in magento despite config being correct.

Tags: magento, paypal

I followed the Magento configuration instructions to the T for how to set up PayPal in Magento, but despite all of that, PayPal still doesn't appear as a payment option to users. Is there something that needs to be configured on PayPal manager to make it appear? Or is there something that could be messing up the checkout option in my theme somewhere. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a custom template? If so, try renaming your theme folder under app/skin so that it falls back to the default Magento theme. This will show if it's a theme related issue or not.

Also make sure you clear all your cache by going to `System > Cache Management`